# Variables "dolprovider" and "admcon7"

Tags: collegescorecard

Hello CollegeScorecard folks, I'm doing some work on updating my college scorecard data file. I'm seeing a couple variables in the documentation (`dolprovider` and `admcon7`). But, I'm not finding the variables in the data files.

I see `dolprovider` documented in the `Institution_Data_Dictionary` tab (and other tabs) of CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx file. For example see lines 2650 & 2651 of the `Institution_Data_Dictionary` tab.

I also see `admcon7` documented in the same way over there in then CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx file. For examples see lines 2652 and 2656 of the `Institution_Data_Dictionary` tab.

It looks like these variables came along with the Aug 2021 update. I'm seeing references to these new variables in the change log under Aug 2021. Could the documentation have been updated (but somehow the data files not updated)?

I think *think* I've thoroughly searched the data files for these variables. But, I'm not finding them in the data files. Has anyone else noticed this? Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

On the [College Scorecard Data](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/) page there is a link to the data on [data.ed.gov](https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files/resources). In the [Most Recent Institution Level Data](https://data.ed.gov/dataset/college-scorecard-all-data-files/resources?resource=823ac095-bdfc-41b0-b508-4e8fc3110082) file, those two columns are found in columns CMZ and CNA. This is the same file as is in the raw data, which is also available on data.ed.gov.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, helpful. I was looking at this set of data files (which includes an entry for each year 1996 through most recent 2018): https://ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip. This data file (if you append into a panel) contains 1986 variables.

The "Most Recent Inst... Data" file contains 2989 variables. The data dict I referenced "CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx" also has the 2989 variables.

Does anyone know if there there a data dictionary specific to the data at: https://ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip ??

Answer (score 0):

With an assist from Alex I believe I have a partial answer to this question. I was referencing the data files here:

```
ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip
```

The data file I was referencing (shown above) contains a subset of columns. The two variables `dolprovider` and `admcon7` are just two of the many not included in the above files. Both `dolprovider` and `admcon7` along with full set of columns are available from:

```
ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data_MMDDYYYY.zip
```

Or currently as of today that is:

```
ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data_02072022.zip
```

The data dictionary available at the address below matches the full complete data set.

```
collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx
```